# Fibonacci secuence Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> t’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

Down two functions. One that calculates fibonacci of a certain number and the other that tries to show the fibonacci sequence up to a certain number using map.
The error occurs when I type fibonacci and a number, for example fibonacci 8
and throws error. What am I doing wrong?

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

fibonacci :: [Integer]
fibonacci = map fib [0..]
```

Comment: Please don't post "there's an error" questions without posting the full error. Your code above looks fine to me, even if the implementation of `fib` is extremely inefficient (requiring exponential time), so in practice it will hardly produce more than a few elements.

Comment: I've run this code and there is no error. Please tell us exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: The error appears when I execute it, not when I drop the program. For example I put fibonacci 8 and there the error occurs

Comment: `fibonacci 8` doesn't work because `fibonacci` is a list, not a function.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro Please edit your question to reflect this addition - don't just write important information in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `fibonacci`, you're writing:

```
> fibonacci 8
(error)
```

But, `fibonacci :: [Integer]` - **`fibonacci` isn't a function** and you can't call it! **`fibonacci` is an infinite list,** so you must use list-based operations to get specific numbers.

The list indexing operator is `(!!) :: [a] -> Integer -> a`, so use that:

```
> fibonacci !! 8
21
```

You could also use `take :: Integer -> [a] -> [a]` to get the first *n* numbers:

```
> take 8 fibonacci
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
```

You can, however do this:

```
> fib 8
21
```

Because `fib :: Integer -> Integer` *is* a function.